# Android Navigation - Popping the current fragment when navigating

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-navigation, android-jetpack-navigation

I have a fragment that can be dynamically navigated to from anywhere in my app, however, when the user leaves this fragment it shouldn't be added to the backstack.

E.g. if a user is at fragment A and navigates to this fragment (B) then to fragment C, when they click back they should arrive at fragment A not fragment B.

---

I have tried calling the following in fragment B:

```
findNavController().navigate(
   resId = R.id.C, 
   navOptions = NavOptions.Builder()
       .setPopUpTo(R.id.B, inclusive = true)
       .build()
)
```

however, this does not work. Additionally, I cannot call this from fragment B:

```
findNavController().navigate(
   resId = R.id.C, 
   navOptions = NavOptions.Builder()
       .setPopUpTo(R.id.A, inclusive = false) // this line is different
       .build()
)
```

as B does not know what its predecessor is.

---

Alternatively, I cannot call something like this in C on back navigation:

```
findNavController().popBackStack(R.id.A, inclusive = false)
```

or something like this in C on fragment creation:

```
findNavController().popBackStack()
```

as C does not necessarily know when its predecessor is either.

---

To make this even harder, I cannot call navigateBack() and then navigate() in fragment B for reasons internal to my app.

I believe this may be possible if I were to check the back stack and add some dynamic calls, however, this feels like a hacky solution.

Is there any neat way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have tried calling the following in fragment B:
>
> ```
> findNavController().navigate(
>    resId = R.id.C, 
>    navOptions = NavOptions.Builder()
>        .setPopUpTo(R.id.B, inclusive = true)
>        .build()
> )
> ```

This solution should normally work, there was an internal bug in my app preventing the navOptions from reaching the navigate() call.